# looking for a theme with the same functionalities as Airbnb Experience, Groupon in France

Tags: wordpress, themes

I'm a beginner in wordpress and I have some questions :

1. I didn't really get the idea of themes in wordpress : Is it possible to use a theme designed for a restaurateur and adapt it to another purpose ?
2. I wanted to know if I can delete a button or a component ..from a theme ?

I'm looking for a theme  with the same functionalities as  Airbnb Experience, Groupon in France..
Looking also for a good udemy or coursera courses that could help me ..
I would be so thankful if someone could help me with that!

Thank you in advance ^-^